# Windows Phone 8.1 XAML StringFormat

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to display some text along with binded data, for example, I have the code:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Shorthand}"  Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" />
```

I want to add some text before 'Shorthand', from what I have read this would be possible by using StringFormat as a property of the Binding, something along the lines of:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Shorthand, StringFormat={0} text I want to add}"  Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" />
```

However this doesn't seem to work, is this no longer the way to do things in 8.1?

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work" is not much of diagnostic.

Comment: aren't you missing the ' in  StringFormat='{0} text I want to add' ?

Comment: Error I was getting was: "The property 'StringFormat' was not found in type 'Binding'"

Comment: You can use _edit_ to add that to the question.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`StringFormat` isn't supported on WinRT. However, you can easily replace it by creating a custom converter:

```
public class StringFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return string.Format(parameter as string, value);
    }  

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then declare it in your page resources:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:StringFormatConverter x:Name="StringFormat"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

And use it in your bindings:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SomeText, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=StringFormat}, ConverterParameter='Hello {0}'}" />
```

Answer (score 16):

Like @KooKiz pointed out `StringFormat` at the moment isn't supported, but you could accomplish the same effect just breaking out your lines into inline Runs without a converter like;

```
<TextBlock>
   <Run Text="Hey I wanted to put this text in front of "/>
   <Run Text="{Binding Path=Shorthand}"/>
   <Run Text=" and I also wanted some text after it. Neato.."/>
</TextBlock>
```

Hope this helps, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I used this approach (Written by Microsoft): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter

It works great!