# StringFormat in XAML

Tags: xaml, data-binding, string-formatting, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to format my `string` to have commas every 3 places, and a decimal if it is not a whole number.  I have checked roughly 20 examples, and this is the closest I have come:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="countTextBlock" Text="{Binding Count, StringFormat={0:n}}" />
```

But I get a `The property 'StringFormat' was not found in type 'Binding'.` error.

Any ideas what is wrong here?  Windows Phone 8.1 appears to differ from WPF, because all of the WPF resources say that this is how it is done.

(The `string` is updated constantly, so I need the code to be in the `XAML`.  I also need it to remain binded.  Unless of course I cannot have my cake and eat it too.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 8.1 XAML StringFormat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127262/windows-phone-8-1-xaml-stringformat)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that, similar to `Binding` in WinRT, `Binding` in Windows Phone Universal Apps doesn't have `StringFormat` property. One possible way to work around this limitation is using `Converter` as explained in [this blog post](http://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/04/26/stringformat-converter-for-windows-store-apps/),

To summarize the post, you can create an `IValueConverter` implmentation that accept string format as parameter :

```
public sealed class StringFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        if (parameter == null)
            return value;

        return string.Format((string)parameter, value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Create a resource of above converter in your XAML, then you can use it like this for example :

```
<TextBlock x:Name="countTextBlock" 
           Text="{Binding Count, 
                          Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter},
                          ConverterParameter='{}{0:n}'}" />
```