# Concat data binding and static text in C#

Tags: c#, data-binding

So I have a textbox with a data binding to it, but I want to add static text in my xaml code.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Preptime}"></TextBlock>
```

This will only show the number of minutes, I want it to be displayed as: "Preparation time: 55 minutes"

```
        public String Preparation
    {
        get { return "Preparation time: " + Preptime + " minutes"; }
    }
```

I know I can use a getter for this which would be a clean solution but there has to be a way to write this directly into my xaml?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some additional searching I found that using runs might be the easiest solution. More info here: [Windows Phone 8.1 XAML StringFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127262/windows-phone-8-1-xaml-stringformat)

```
                <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="Preparation time: "></Run>
                <Run Text="{Binding Preptime}"></Run>
                <Run Text=" minutes."></Run>
            </TextBlock>
```

Comment: If you are working on Windows Phone or a Windows App Store app please add that tag next time. It does not support all the features a desktop App has.

Answer (score 8):

Use the property [`StringFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat(v=vs.110).aspx) on the binding.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Preptime, StringFormat=Preparation time: {0} minutes}"></TextBlock>
```

It behaves the same as [`String.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't supported, I get the error: "The property 'StringFormat' was not found in type 'Binding'". You could create a custom converter but take a look at my answer below, it works and is pretty clean.

Answer (score 2):

You can use StringFormat directly on TextBlock's Text property, just like you used string.format in your .cs