# Set TextBlock Text to Binding + String

Tags: listview, binding, uwp, windows-10

I have a ListView with multiple TextBlocks in it. Is it possible to have something such as this?

```xml
<TextBlock Name="SonstSchnitt" Text="{Binding testsPercent} + %"/>
```

Comment: Use a converter for example?

Comment: @Romasz I found a property called "StringFormat" in WPF. Is there something similar to this in UWP?

Comment: You may take [a look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24127468/2681948).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Run` inside the `TextBlock` to achieve this:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="{Binding testsPercent}" /> %
</TextBlock>
```